# Create coupon that sets the shipping rate to a specific amount

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon

I need to create a coupon that sets the shipping rate of an item to a specific amount.

For instance, if the customer purchases any item and uses this specific coupon code (cart rule), their shipping amount is always set to $5, no matter what.

So if a customer buys a $3 item and their shipping is $10, this will always lower their shipping to $5, giving a total of $8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento Shopping cart rules ***do not have any feature like the discount on Shipping amount***. It has the **only able to change the shipping to free Shipping means Shipping price to 0.**.

If you want to do like then you have to work on Shipping carrier method or have to use any 3rd party extension like it.